# Kernel parameter quiet versus loglevel=4 and debug versus loglevel=7

Tags: kernel-parameters

Besides the possibility of userspace applications that care which one you use reading `/proc/cmdline`, what is the difference between using the kernel parameter `quiet`, versus `loglevel=4`, and the parameter `debug`, versus `loglevel=7`? Is there any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, they're absolutely the same.  The following is a quote from [Linux Kernel in a Nutshell by Greg Kroah-Hartman](http://files.kroah.com/lkn/)

> debug
>
> Enable kernel debugging.
>
> Cause the kernel log level to be set to the debug level, so that all
>   debug messages will be printed to the console at boot time.
>
> ---
>
> quiet
>
> Disable all log messages.
>
> Set the default kernel log level to KERN_WARNING (4), which
>   suppresses all messages during boot except extremely serious ones.
>   (Log levels are defined under the loglevel parameter.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any messages with `quiet` or `loglevel=0`. I do see a (innocuous) message of failure with a value between `1-3` for `loglevel`. I see even more messages with values higher than that. It seems `quiet` is the same as `loglevel=0`, and `debug` is the same as `loglevel=7`.